# MobileFirst 7.1 - How to use CLI for current installed Liberty Core with MobileFirst server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I recently installed Liberty Core server, created a new Profile, installed MobileFirst Platform Server and deployed a MobileFirst runtime environment with the Server Configuration Tool in MacBook.

Instead of installing in default directory(Application/ibm/*) I choose to install under custom directory (Users/username/LibertyCore).

I started the server manually installed adapters and *.wlapp from worklight console.

Instead of doing this manual deployment I want to do it from command line? My understanding is I have to use MFP command line utility.

I installed MFP CLI utility then parsed to the App Project folder to build and deploy to currently installed Liberty Core server I see issue with MFP PUSH it says server is not started though server is running.

So when I do MFP Info I found that CLI is pointing to completely different set up. How can I make CLI to point to currently installed Liberty Server.

Comment: Did you try first mfp start inside the project folder from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can run "mfp help" to see all available CLI commands.

There is the command "mfp server". Using this command you can add additional server definitions: "mfp server add". Run the command and follow the on-screen instructions to add a server definition for your remote server...

Once you've added it, you can use "mfp push your-remote-server-name" to push the artifacts to the remote server.

Comment: [?] Enter the new value for 'url': http://10.146.17.130:9080
[?] Edit another server setting? Yes
[?] Select value to change: context root (worklightadmin)
[?] Enter the new value for 'context root': worklightadmin
[?] Edit another server setting? No
Verifying Server Configuration...
Couldn't connect to server 'worklight' at 'http://10.146.17.130:9080'.
failed to retrieve runtime information: Unexpected token <: HTTP 404 - Not Found